# dd: opening `/dev/sdb': Permission denied

Tags: dd, umount

I'm trying to write a Linux image in a CF card, as is shown in 
[Google Code Archive: debian-for-alix - InstalationAndFirstSteps.wiki](http://code.google.com/p/debian-for-alix/wiki/InstalationAndFirstSteps):

When I do:

```bash
sudo bzcat debian-for-alix-cf2g.img.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=16k
```

I get:

```bash
dd: opening `/dev/sdb': Permission denied
```

I can see in mtab that `/dev/sdb` corresponds to the target CF connected to a USB port.

The line in the mtab file is:

```bash
/dev/sdb1 /media/2020-2020 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush 0 0
```

Before executing

```bash
sudo bzcat debian-for-alix-cf2g.img.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=16k
```

I unmounted the device with

```bash
umount /media/2020-2020
```

Why can't I write to `/dev/sdb` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try running it as root:

```
user ~ $ sudo -s
Password: 
root ~ # bzcat debian-for-alix-cf2g.img.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=16k
```

The way you tried doesn't work probably because prepending `sudo` runs `bzcat` as root, but not `dd`.

Answer (score 6):

or put sudo after the pipe, | sudo dd...

```
sudo bzcat debian-for-alix-cf2g.img.bz2 | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=16k
```

Although this might ask for password twice, so I actually prefer using sudo -s or sudo -i

Comment: A useful answer.  Would you edit it to be a complete example please?